# Delphi form minimise issue

Tags: delphi

I currently have a delphi 7 project sitting in front of me and what the original creators of the software have done is used the main form as a launch pad for another form which contains the actual controls and logic behind the entire application. So basically, form1 loads up, is set to invisible and another form (the form with all the UI controls and logic) is created and shown, its a strange way to do things, but its the way they did it.

Now I'm not familiar with the way delphi 7 handles its forms, but this second window, the window with all the controls on, whenever i click the minimise button, the form does not drop down to the taskbar as one would expect, but rather, resizes so that only the minimise, maximise and close buttons are visible and then places itself at the bottom left of the screen, just above the start menu.

the creation of this second window is:

```
frmPlatform := TfrmPlatform.Create(frmMain);
ModalResult := frmPlatform.ShowModal;
```

where frmMain is the invisible form.

My question is, why does the second window not minimize as one would expect and drop to the taskbar? and how do i get it to work,

thanks

Comment: The top answer below appears to be the only answer I've been able to find. You should consider marking that answer as "Accepted".

Answer (score 9):

Standard behaviour of forms I'm afraid as the mainform is by default the only form shown by Delphi on the taskbar. You can however set other forms to appear on the taskbar as well:

```
procedure TForm1.CreateParams
   (var Params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(Params);
  Params.ExStyle := Params.ExStyle
                    or WS_EX_APPWINDOW;
end;
```

And you can hide your current main form of course as well, see: http://delphi.about.com/od/adptips1999/qt/hidefromtaskbar.htm, and http://delphi.about.com/od/delphitips2008/qt/hide_taskbutton.htm for D2007 and up.

Comment: Thank you. I've been digging the internet for this solution after a bunch of failed ones. Works perfectly (assuming Application.MainFormOnTaskbar = True).

Answer (score 0):

I think you will find that in standard Delphi apps only the main (first) form will be shown in the task bar. Since your main form is invisible that's your issue.  The minimize is probably due to the second form being called with show modal rather than simply show.

Can you remove the first form or change which form is the main form?  This can be done from the project settings page.

Comment: If you change the mainform through the project's options, the new mainform will be created by the dpr, that may not be what the OP wants.

Comment: was actually considering doing this, but since i just started looking over the system today, i'm not yet knowledgeable enough to know what repercussions that will have down the line. So i was hoping for a quick fix for the time being

Comment: @Marjan - Possibly, but mainform implies that it is created in the dpr since it is not the mainform otherwise.

Comment: @Toby: Actually, the mainform is the first form created through Application.CreateForm, regardless of where that call is placed. It's just the IDE that puts it in the dpr...

Comment: @Marjan -  Generally the first form created by Application.CreateForm would be in the dpr.  I guess it could be created in a .pas file if you were being very obscure.  I understand how the project options interact with the .dpr file, what I dont understand is the point you are making?

Comment: @Toby: the point I was making is that changing the mainform through the project options would change the order in which forms were created (the main form always goes first) and that changing the creation order could be an unwanted side effect. See now that I missed "first" in "will be created by the dpr". Sorry for the confusion.